# Sublime Search/Replace adds New Line

Tags: sublimetext2

When I do a simple search/replace, without any regex, ST2 adds a newline to each replacement.   What am I doing wrong?

Below, I want to change spaces to commas.  It does so, but also throws in a newline.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Perhaps you inadvertently pasted a newline into the replace with field?

Comment: Try clearing everything in the replace box and paste your replacing string.

Comment: I hit backspace all the way to the left, hit the comma key, and then press the "Replace All" button with the mouse.  So no extra keys are making it into the field.  Are you saying that you cannot replicate the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the text you would like to replace is somewhat limited in size, here is a workaround. It doesn't even incorporate the builtin replace feature, and it can be somewhat slow for large text files.

Hit CMD + F (or CTRL + F) to bring up the Find dialog on the bottom of the window. Enter whatever string you'd like into the text field. Click the "Find All" button, and you'll get multiple write positions into the file. You can write in two places at once! If you've done it correctly, you'll see not just one blinking vertical line (which usually indicates the position in the file that the read/write pointer is at), but multiple. You can then type as usual into the file, and it should add text in multiple places.